# Subversion property to JAR/WAR manifest in Jenkins

Tags: java, svn, properties, jenkins, manifest

Is is possible to get SVN property information (specifically svn:mergeinfo) to appear in MANIFEST.MF when building a Java JAR/WAR with Jenkins and Maven?

I have a setup where we merge from trunk to release branches in order to kick off Jenkins builds with the right profiles for the target environments - we're working towards continuous release.

I'd like to be able to know which trunk revision is currently deployed on a server by examining the manifest in the Tomcat webapp. The svn:mergeinfo property seems good for this, but I'm open to alternative options if there's a better way.

Note: The branch may have been updated since the last deployment, so I can't rely on the current value of the property in the branch (which is my current approach).

Comment: I think, subwcrev (or it's Linux-brother) way will be more correct, if  Jenkins can run it in task

Comment: Interesting. If I could use a pre-build step to run a script that retrieves the property and then transfer that to a variable that can be accessed by the build.

Answer (score 2):

When you merge subtree with subtree, svn:mergeinfo will appear (updated) on the root of merge-target (branch-directory in your case), not in any object inside target.

I.e - you can

- get mergeinfo
- update property of any object inside with this new data

but not in the time of merge, and storing changed data will be additional commit to branch after merge-commit

**Add-on**

Discovered (by accident) new svn-command and easiest way to get latest revision, merged to TARGET.

`svn mergeinfo FROM TO` will show list of all revisions, merged from FROM to TO. `mergeinfo | tail -1` will be latest merged

Comment: This is helpful, as it explains what I'm seeing when I merge. It seems to commit the updated property with the merge commit (and if not I can commit twice, that's no problem). I'm not clear how to go from here to exposing the property at build time, but your comment about subwcrev/brother is interesting.

Comment: @Carboni - main questions for "exposing the property at build time" is "how you build" - from Jenkins WC of branch (or directly `cat` from repo?), on Repo host or on remote? Depending from answers, you can call on build time: `subwcrev` (for WC-source), `svn info <SRC>` (with post-parsing) (for WC and Repo-URL), `svn log -l 1 --xml`

Comment: We're building from a Jenkins working copy. Jenkins is on a different host to the repository. I've tried svn info http://host/svn/folder and svn log -l 1 --xml but they don't seem to be giving me useful information for accessing svn:mergeinfo.

Comment: So I've poked around a bit and come up with: `svn propget -r HEAD svn:mergeinfo`, which prints out the information I need. Now, getting that into a build step and capturing the output as a variable would be the answer.

Comment: @Carboni - well, one second please: if you merge (all revisions) **from trunk** (from first unmerged to latest in trunk), why do you afraid to use *last revision number* of trunk?!

Comment: If I understand correctly (and I'm not sure I do) HEAD will get me the latest version of the repo as a whole, effectively the last revision number of trunk (or any path in the repo). Bear in mind that whilst I'm reviewing merge changes before committing for build, additional commits may be happening in trunk, so I believe I need Jenkins to look at snv:mergeinfo for HEAD in the branch WC it has checked out?

Comment: @Carboni: "HEAD will get me the latest version of the repo as a whole" - yes. For svn log -l 1 trunk you'll get **last revision in trunk at the moment of request** - so if between merging and commiting mergeset you have some remarkable time, last trunk will change, yes. If you want still have atomic operation, you can (except `svnpropget svn:mergeinfo .` in branch WC /no -r because mergeinfo isn't revision property, "." for path (root), for which we request property/) try: merge into intermediate branch (copied from release-branch at start) in post-commit hook... TBC

Comment: @Carboni - hook must to process only *special signal commit* and in this case revision of this commit (known to post-commit hook) will be data for MANIFEST without parsing mergeinfo

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.. it sounds more complex than I'd like. I really just want Jenkins to check out the branch and add svn:mergeinfo to its build parameters. After that, going from a build parameter into the manifest is no problem.